# How should I put an android library online

Tags: maven, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I made an android library this way. I created a new project and then I created a new module. I created the object I needed. Now the problem is: how do I use this library in other android projects? I had thought of uploading it online, so as to go to the gradle of each of the projects and import it. The only problem is that I can't understand how I can do it all. 
I hope you have addressed the problem efficiently. thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see how to write effective questions in stackoverflow. (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)Show us some code if you are having any error.

Comment: If you're building these libraries yourself you can add it to your local Maven repository. If you want to publish the artifact for the general population then https://maven.apache.org/repository/guide-central-repository-upload.html.